# How to pass a confirmation message from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an edit tag form in the `Edit` view, when form is submitted, I want to check if that ID exists in the database table then update it, and after updating go to the Edit view again and display the Success message.

If the ID does not exist in the table then go to the Edit view and display error message.

With the following code I can pass update the values but I don't know how to pass the **success** and **error** message to the view and how to display that message in the View.

```
public IActionResult Edit(EditTagRequest editTagRequest)
{

    var tag = new Tag
    {
        Id  = editTagRequest.Id,
        Title = editTagRequest.Title,
    };

    var existingTag = _context.Tags.Find(editTagRequest.Id);

    if (existingTag != null) {

        existingTag.FirstName = tag.FirstName; 
        existingTag.LastName = tag.LastName;

        _context.SaveChanges();
        
        //how to pass success message data 
        return View("Edit");

    }
    
    //how to pass error message data here
    return View("Edit");
}
```

I tried the above code. I does most of the work that I am trying to achieve, but I am unable to figure how to send the confirmation message from controller to view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option would probably be to add a `Message` to the `ViewBag` in your action method for example:

```csharp
public IActionResult Edit(EditTagRequest editTagRequest)
{

    var tag = new Tag
    {
        Id  = editTagRequest.Id,
        Title = editTagRequest.Title,
    };

    var existingTag = _context.Tags.Find(editTagRequest.Id);

    if (existingTag != null) {

        existingTag.FirstName = tag.FirstName; 
        existingTag.LastName = tag.LastName;

        _context.SaveChanges();
        
        //how to pass success message data 
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Edit succeeded."
        return View("Edit");

    }
    
    //how to pass error message data here
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Edit failed."
    return View("Edit");
}
```

which you can then reference in your View:

```html
<p>@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</p>
```

You could also consider using a ViewModel, Microsoft has a lot of tutorials on ASP.NET Core MVC including the use of ViewModels e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-search-by-genre